# Is it grammatical to use adverb between "have" and "been" in present perfect: "They should have actually been insured against everything."

Tags: adverbs, word-order

> They should have **actually** been insured against everything.

Is it correct to use adverb between the two components of present perfect i.e. *have* and *been*?

Comment: In writing, the location after the modal is preferred: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should+have+never+been%2Cshould+never+have+been&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshould%20have%20never%20been%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20never%20have%20been%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the meaning of "*actually*" here, but nonetheless, it is **grammatically OK**.  Other adverbs that fall into the same category are "*ever*", "*never*", "*always*", "*already*", "*scarcely*", "*rarely*", "*seldom*" (all are "frequency" types), "*seemingly*", "*likely*", "*probably*" and others.

You can search for any combination of those adverbs with "have" and "been" and discover numerous occurrences, I am sure.